# google compute can not create instance

Tags: python, windows, google-compute-engine, instances, gcloud

my python version is 2.7.8
my google cloud config is:

```
C:\Users\sheng\Desktop>gcloud config list
[compute]
region = asia-east1
zone = asia-east1-c
[core]
account = foretribe@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = foretribebigquery
user_output_enabled = True
```

my gcloud version is:

```
C:\Users\sheng>gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.45

app-engine-python 1.9.17
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.6
bq 2.0.18
bq-win 2.0.18
compute 2015.01.22
core 2015.01.22
core-win 2014.10.14
dns 2015.01.15
gae-python 2014.05.06
gae-python-launcher-win 1.9.17
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-win 1.16.5
gsutil 4.7
gsutil-win 4.6
preview 2015.01.22
sql 2015.01.15
windows-ssh-tools 2014.07.15
```

when I try to create new instance for my google app engine:

```
 C:\Users\sheng\Desktop>gcloud compute instances create myapp --project  foretribebigquery --scopes datastore foretribe@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 183, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 179, in main
_cli.Execute()
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 470, in Execute
for s in args:
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1703, in parse_args
args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1735, in parse_known_args
namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1923, in _parse_known_args
positionals_end_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1900, in consume_positionals
take_action(action, args)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1809, in take_action
action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 229, in __call__
super(CloudSDKSubParsersAction, self).__call__(
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1111, in __call__
namespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1735, in parse_known_args
namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1923, in _parse_known_args
positionals_end_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1900, in consume_positionals
take_action(action, args)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1809, in take_action
action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 229, in __call__
super(CloudSDKSubParsersAction, self).__call__(
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1111, in __call__
namespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1735, in parse_known_args
namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1923, in _parse_known_args
positionals_end_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1900, in consume_positionals
take_action(action, args)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\argparse
\__init__.py", line 1809, in take_action
action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 227, in __call__
if self._calliope_command:
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 824, in LoadSubElement
self._cli_generator, self._config_hooks, self.SubParser(),
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 940, in __init__
parser_group=parser_group,
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 511, in __init__
help_func=help_func,
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 584, in _AssignParser

File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 652, in _AcquireArgs
return
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\co
mpute\subcommands\instances\create.py", line 57, in Args
operation_type='create')
File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\compute\lib\utils.py", line 86, in AddZoneFlag
action=actions.StoreProperty(properties.VALUES.compute.zone))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StoreProperty'
```

Any one know what is that Attribute is? How to set the attribute StroeProperty?

Comment: Looks like something is out of whack in your gcloud installation, with utils.py and calliope/actions.py being from different releases.  My `gcloud version` says `Google Cloud SDK 0.9.45` -- what about yours?  Maybe try removing and reinstalling and then doing a `gcloud components update`?

Comment: @AlexMartelli I added my gcloud version

Comment: Looks right but is made up wrong (for me the `actions` module **does** have `StoreProperty` -- it's a function) so I repeat the recommendation to completely remove the gcloud sdk, reinstall, update.  Your local installation must have been modified somehow.  You may want to try editing that utils.py and at line 85 (just before it now breaks) add a `print(repr(actions))` to see if the problem may not be from an **unrelated** `actions` module getting imported, but I doubt it as `util.py` very carefully specifies where it's importing it from.